# Restore Default Ubuntu 22.04 DNS Settings

Tags: networking, dns

**Situation**
Prior, to properly backing up my freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 with Timeshift... I attempted to instead install dsnmasq for local web development.  Of course, I broke my DNS and now my fresh install has no internet access :-(

**Error**
These are the exact step from my personal notes that caused the error:

```
1. Disable & stop systemd resolved  

    $ sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved  
    $ sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved

2. Remove symlink on `/etc/resolv.conf` & remove the file

    $ ls -lh /etc/resolv.conf  
    $ sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf

3. create new /etc/resolv.conf
   
   sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 127.0.0.1" > /etc/resolv.conf'
```

After item 3.) above, I completely lost internet access.

**Troubleshooting**

1.) I easily re-enabled  `systemd-resolved`

**Update:**
@keff suggested solution below, seems to be correct, but it does not work.

1.) I created a virtualbox installation of ubuntu 22.04 and made a copy of `/etc/resolv.conf`  that I put in my shared folder and took a screenshot of the `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf` output.

2.) I followed @keff's instructions and compared the results to my virtualbox output... they match.  I rebooted the machine to ensure all possible services get a restart.

DNS just isn't working, although it is correctly configured.  I have two laptops connected to the same wifi connection, so I know the wifi is working correctly.

I am stumped.

(yes, port 53 is open in ufw)

**Question**
The part of my foolery that eludes me is, *"How do I re-establish the  `/etc/resolv.conf`  symlink, so that box once again has outside internet access?"*

Comment: does a systemctl restart resolved
help until the next boot ?

Answer (score 1):

To recreate the symlink for `/etc/resolv.conf`, run the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resov.conf
```

This will create a symlink from `/etc/resov.conf` to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`, which lists `127.0.0.53` as the local caching stub resolver.